# Trying to import some modules but get "..which can not be read"

Tags: d

I am new to D and am trying to create a simple starter project with sub modules. I have been following the [d2d](https://github.com/Prophets-of-Profit/d2d) source structure, as an example, but I can't get my project to compile using DUB.

My folder structure is:

```
Ranger
  examples
    template0     <== compiling in this directory
      source
        app.d
      dub.json
source
  ranger
    geometry
      package.d
      point.d
    package.d
```

`app.d` contains:

```d
import std.stdio;

import ranger;

void main()
{
    writeln("Edit source/app.d to start your project.");
}
```

ranger/package.d:

```d
module ranger;

public import ranger.geometry;
```

ranger/geometry/package.d:

```d
module ranger.geometry;

public import ranger.geometry.point;
```

When I compile from the `template0` directory it keeps failing:

> dub build --force

> Invalid source/import path: /home/iposthuman/Documents/Development/D/Ranger/examples/template0/~/Documents/Development/D/Ranger/source

> Performing "debug" build using /home/iposthuman/dlang/dmd-2.084.0/linux/bin64/dmd for x86_64.

> template0 ~master: building configuration "application"...

> /home/iposthuman/Documents/Development/D/Ranger/source/ranger/package.d(5,15): Error: module `geometry` is in file 'ranger/geometry.d' which cannot be read

> import path[0] = source import path[1](https://github.com/Prophets-of-Profit/d2d) = /home/iposthuman/Documents/Development/D/Ranger/source
> import path[2] = /home/iposthuman/dlang/dmd-2.084.0/linux/bin64/../../src/phobos
> import path[3] = /home/iposthuman/dlang/dmd-2.084.0/linux/bin64/../../src/druntime/import

> /home/iposthuman/dlang/dmd-2.084.0/linux/bin64/dmd failed with exit code 1.

1. I don't understand why the import path has two paths smashed together not do I know how to fix it.
2. I don't understand the involving geometry.d because there isn't a file called geometry.d--but there is a folder with a package. ...I am confused.

My dub.json contains what I believe is the correct path to my ranger source code:

```
{
    "authors": [
        "William Cleveland"
    ],
    "copyright": "Copyright © 2019, William Cleveland",
    "description": "A minimal D application.",
    "license": "MIT",
    "name": "template0",
    "importPaths": [
        "source",
        "~/Documents/Development/D/Ranger/source"
    ]
}
```

Am I using DUB wrong or configuring the json wrong???

I didn't think using D was going to be this difficult just to get something basic working. I have searched everywhere on Modules and find only trivial examples.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure whether this is causing your problem but you source path should be relative. Use "../../../source" not the absolute "~/Documents/Development/D/Ranger/source"

Comment: LOL. I tried that and a bunch of other combos but no luck.

Comment: It would work if the directory tree in your question was correct, but I guess `source` is also a subdirectory of `Ranger`? Then it should be two `..`s instead of three.

Answer (score 4):

Dub doesn't translate `~` to your home directory. `~` is POSIX-speak, but dub is a cross-platform application.

Either use `/home/iposthuman/Documents/Development/D/Ranger/source` or `../../source`.

Preferrably the latter, because it won't break when your username changes or you share your project with someone else.

Comment: Yup. Tried absolute as well but DUB just seems to append stuff together.

Answer (score 1):

I think weltensturm's answer is the right idea but slightly off. I would change

```
"importPaths": [
    "source",
    "~/Documents/Development/D/Ranger/source"
]
```

to

```
"importPaths": [
    "source",
    "../../../source"
]
```

Basically you just need to go back one more directory to access source.

> I don't understand the involving geometry.d because there isn't a file called geometry.d--but there is a folder with a package. ...I am confused.

This is because when you import a module, dub expects there to be a file with that name or a package.d file like you have inside of a folder with the name of the module.  So if you do `import foo;` there should be a file called foo.d or package.d inside a folder called foo which has `module foo;` at the beginning of it.  I think what you have is right, but since your import path is wrong, dub is looking in the wrong place for geometry.d or the folder geometry.

Side note, you could always turn the folder that you are importing into a package using dub.  And run `dub add-local ./`.  Then you can add it as a dependency to the other project by doing `"my-project": "~master"`